# How to paint to a bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, rendering

First of all: I'm sort of new to GDI, so please excuse me (and do let me know) if I make any misconceptions.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to let my WM_PAINT code paint to a bitmap instead of to the screen with BeginPaint(). I would also like to display the bitmap on the screen while also displaying other data on top of it(that doesn't get saved to the bitmap).

Could anyone tell me the win32 functions and datatypes needed to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908165.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to paint somewhere other than your window, you'll need a new DC. You can use `HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC([your window hdc]);` to create one.

Now you'll need a bitmap to paint to. Use `HBITMAP memBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap ([your window hdc],[your window width],[your window height]);` (assuming you want one the same size, if it isn't then `StretchBlt` should do the trick) to create that.

Note that when you're done using these you'll need to `DeleteObject (memBitmap);` and `DeleteDC (memDC);` to clean up.

Once created, select the bitmap into your offscreen DC via `SelectObject (memDC, memBitmap);`

Now do all of your drawing to `memDC`. Once finished, use the `BitBlt()` function with source hdc as memDC and destination hdc as your window's DC. Don't forget to delete what you created.

Comment: Since we must use CreateCompatibleBitmap() to create a bitmap compatible with a device context... In the program I also want to allow the user to load a bitmap from a file. How would I make that bitmap compatible then?